# importing python twitter fails on windows 7 (no module named request_oauthlib)

Tags: python, twitter

I am trying to import the python twitter 2.0 package on windows 7. Currently only running Ipython 2.7 as my main python shell, but import twitter fails.
Always get the msg no module named request_oauthlib found.
I am pretty new to python so might overlook something basic.
Appreciate any thoughts!

Comment: How did you install the package?

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out now. I installed it by running setup.py but now used pip via Anaconda

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `tweepy`? It's really easy to install and use :)

Just run `pip install tweepy` (or `pip3 install tweepy` if that doesn't work), and you are ready to go!

You can create your ap in https://apps.twitter.com/ and do with it whatever you want.

[Here you have](https://github.com/Mikelsr/EveryPossibleTweet) a really easy guide to installing tweepy (and pip, if you don't have it already) and a example of a Python Twitter bot :) (Open code!)

I hope this helped, and if you need further help, just ask!

edit: after installing tweepy, obviously you have to `import tweepy` in your Python program xD